# Simple mathematical operations (add, sub, mul, div) in C++11 template

Tags: c++, c++11, template, variadic

I made a simple script to implement basic mathematics operations by using variadic functions. I would like to know if my implementation is correct.

The code only works for Visual C++ compiler Nov 2013 CTP (CTP_Nov2013).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T add(T&& item = T())
{
    return forward<T>(item);
}

template <typename T, typename ... Types>
auto add(T&& first, Types&& ... rest)
    -> decltype(first + add(forward<Types>(rest)...))
{
    return forward<T>(first) + add(forward<Types>(rest)...);
}

template <typename T>
T sub(T&& i = T())
{
    return forward<T>(i);
}

template <typename T, typename ... Types>
auto sub(T&& first, Types&& ... rest)
-> decltype(forward<T>(first) - sub(forward<Types>(rest)...))
{
    return forward<T>(first) - sub(forward<Types>(rest)...);
}

template <typename T>
T multiple(T&& i = T())
{
    return forward<T>(i);
}

template <typename T, typename ... Types>
auto multiple(T&& first, Types&& ... rest)
-> decltype(forward<T>(first) * multiple(std::forward<Types>(rest)...))
{
    return forward<T>(first) * multiple(forward<Types>(rest)...);
}

template <typename T>
T divide(T&& item = T())
{
    return forward<T>(item);
}

template <typename T, typename ... Types>
auto divide(T&& first, Types&& ... rest)
    -> decltype(forward<T>(first) / divide(forward<Types>(rest)...))
{
    if (divide(forward<Types>(rest)...) == 0)
        throw "Opps divided by Zero";
    return forward<T>(first) / divide(forward<Types>(rest)...);
}

template<typename... Types>
void termnate(Types&&...)
{
    std::cout << '\n';
}

template<typename... Types>
void result(Types&&... t)
{
    termnate{ ([&]{ std::cout << forward<Types>(t) << ' '; }(), 1)... };
}

int main()
{
    result(     add(1, 2.5, 3, 4, 5), " = ", "1 + 2,5 + 3 + 4 + 5");

    result(sub(sub(sub(sub(1, 2.5), 3), 4), 5), " = ", "1 - 2.5 - 3 - 4 - 5"); // OK = -13.5

    result(multiple(1, 2.5, 3, 4, 5), " = ", "1 x 2.5 x 3 x 4 x 5");

    result(divide(divide(divide(divide(1, 2.5), 3), 4.5), 5), " = ", "1 / 2.5 / 3 / 4 / 5"); // OK = .005926


    cout << add("\nTest ", "template: ", string("PASS\n"));
}
```

Comment: Subtraction and division are not associative, so I am not sure how to define correctness of their variadic versions. Obviously, division by 0 returning 1 is wrong.

Comment: @vnp ... yes, i was testing static_assert() but it won't be, i dunno why

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you should be using [`forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) when you pass on the `&&` move references in the recursive calls.

Comment: @glampert i tried to implement `std::forword` but i wont be worked with me. i'm working on it right now.

Comment: Don't forget to explicitly pass the template type (e.g.: `std::forward<T>(x)`), it can't figure out the type by itself otherwise.

Comment: [This question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62485/writeln-and-format-with-variadic-templates) is somewhat related.

Comment: @glampert .. thanks that really deserve tobe an answer

Comment: @glampert .. according to the answer in that link, `std::forword` is static_cast. i haven't look at it in its file. but i think in code doesn't need it because of the recursive is also a return T as template

Comment: Yes, indeed, I'm not 100% sure if `forward` would make a difference here in the code generated, though it seems to be the recommended usage...

Comment: @glampert ... i agree .. once again thanks a lot

Comment: According to the link above *"If a call to wrapper() passes an rvalue std::string, then T is deduced to std::string (not std::string&, const std::string&, or std::string&&), and std::forward ensures that an rvalue reference is passed to foo."*, so if I understand, the move reference would get lost in the second call, thus the need for `forward`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing around move references, the recommended is to [`forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) the parameters to ensure that the move reference is preserved:

```
template <typename T, typename ... Types>
auto add(T&& first, Types&& ... rest) 
    -> decltype(first + add(std::forward<Types>(rest)...))
{
    return first + add(std::forward<Types>(rest)...);
}
```

Note that you have to explicitly provide the template type to `std::forward()`. It would deduce the wrong type otherwise.